# onBackPressed() animation issue

Tags: java, android, animation, onbackpressed

I'm trying to override the onBackPressed() method to set my own animation but what's happening is it actually slides from my activity to the same one and then show the new activity.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);
}
```

And here are the animations:

Slide out right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:duration="400" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%" />
<alpha android:duration="400" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

Slide in left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator= "false" >
<translate android:duration = "400" android:fromXDelta = "-100%" android:toXDelta = "0%" />
<alpha android:duration = "400" android:fromAlpha = "0.0" android:toAlpha = "1.0" />
</set>
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Check this; http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-change-the-back-button-behaviour/

Answer (score 1):

`super.onBackPressed();` delete this line and then work

this is translate **slide_in_from_left**

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-300%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
  </set>
```

**slide_in_from_right**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="300%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
  </set>
```

**slide_out_to_left**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-300%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
  </set>
```

**slide_out_to_right**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="300%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
  </set>
```

/

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);
   // add which work after you back.
}
```

and add function which are you work in press back.

Comment: I tried to remove `super.onBackPressed();` but the back button doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: What I did is this: `Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);` but I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try to solve it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);


}
```

Comment: I've just tried it, still the same issue thought. I really don't understand why :/

Comment: @primaëlquemerais That's partially good solution, but `onKeyDown()` listener still working, you may also need to change it. Check the links in my answer and in my comment

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here is an answer from [Android Developers Blog - Back and other hard keys: three stories](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html)

> If you were to survey the base applications in the Android platform,
>   you would notice a fairly common pattern: add a little bit of magic to
>   intercept the BACK key and do something different. To do this right,
>   the magic needs to look something like this:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
>     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
>         // do something on back.
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
> }
> ```
>
> How to intercept the BACK key in an Activity is also one of the common
>   questions we see developers ask, so as of 2.0 we have a new little API
>   to make this more simple and easier to discover and get right:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
> // do something on back.
> return;
> }
> ```
>
> If this is all you care about doing, and you're not worried about
>   supporting versions of the platform before 2.0, then you can stop
>   here. Otherwise, read on.

So your code should look like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);
   finish();
}
```

and

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left);
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Also tried that and the same issue occurs, it's like if both animations were apllying to the same activity and then he changes activity. :/

Comment: Thanks, I've finally made it work, I've just changed the animations I was using which is pretty bizarre as it shouldn't be working like that, but thanks anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this once if this works fine to you then you might have some problem with some other section

**slide_out_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

**slide_up_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

and in your activity add this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_dialog, R.anim.slide_out_down);
    }
```

Comment: It changes the animations but still the same issue, I don't think the problems comes from the animations, but I've tried some of my other animations and strangely it works Oo.